# changing alpha levels while using color.lerp in unity5

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite, renderer, lerp

I am using color.lerp on a sprite renderer to interpolate between yellow and red based on values I have in a dataset. I also want the transparency of the sprites to depend on the value so lower values will be more transparent. The color.lerp works fine but I am now having trouble getting the alpha levels of the sprite to depend on the value as well! Here is my code so far:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class Intensity : MonoBehaviour {

public float value;
private float alpha;

void Start() {

    if (GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ()) {
        SpriteRenderer r = GetComponent<SpriteRenderer> ();
        r.color = new Color32 ();
        r.color = Color.Lerp (Color.yellow, Color.red, value / 100);
        }

    if (GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ()) {
        MeshRenderer r = GetComponent<MeshRenderer> ();
        Material m = r.material;
        Color c = new Color ();
        m.color = c;
        alpha = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, value/100) ;
        c.a = alpha;
    }
}
```

}

Any ideas to make this work would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you,
Jen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this code:

```
    Material m = r.material;
    Color c = new Color ();
    m.color = c;
    alpha = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, value/100) ;
    c.a = alpha;
```

Because `Color` is a struct, any `get` and `set` properties such as `Material.color` will [pass by value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/373419/whats-the-difference-between-passing-by-reference-vs-passing-by-value). This means that `c` and `m.color` are separate values that don't affect each other.

You can avoid that by assigning to `m.color` last:

```
Color c = Color.Lerp(newYellow, Color.red, value / 100);
c.a = Mathf.Lerp(0, 1, value/100);
m.color = c;
```

If that doesn't make sense, see if you can understand why this won't work:

```
m.color.a = 0;
```

You instead have to get the value, make a change, and assign the new value:

```
Color c = m.color;
c.a = 0;
m.color = c;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help!